# Duplicate multiple class styles with different backgrounds with an SCSS function

Tags: css, sass

I have a list of classes which are identical, but need to have different background references inside them:

```
    .name-one {
        @include thumb-source;
        background: url('../name-one.png') no-repeat;
    }

    .name-two {
        @include thumb-source;
        background: url('../name-two.png') no-repeat;
    }

    .name-three {
        @include thumb-source;
        background: url('../name-three.png') no-repeat;
    }

and it goes on for a while ...
```

As you can see the class name also copies the file name. I'm wondering whether there's a way to write a function using scss to pass an array with my class names in it and cut down on repetition significantly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@each` :

```
$list: "one", "two", "three";
@each $item in $list {
    .name-#{$cat} {
        @include thumb-source;
        background: url('../name-#{$cat}.png') no-repeat;
    }
}
```

**[@each Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive)**

Answer (score 1):

If the class names are sequential you'd be better off using an actual number, that way you can use a `@for` loop.

```
$total: 4;

@for $i from 1 to $total {
  .name-#{$i} {
    @include thumb-source;
    background: url('../name-#{$i}.png') no-repeat;
  }
}
```

I'd also add a class to each of those items so you don't need to `@include thumb-source;` on each one. That's a lot of boat.

```
<div class="name name-1"></div>
<div class="name name-2"></div>
<div class="name name-3"></div>
```

Then do:

```
$total: 4;

.name {
  @include thumb-source;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  @for $i from 1 to $total {
    &.name-#{$i} {
      background-image: url('../name-#{$i}.png');
    }
  }
}
```